# Why is Rails displaying validation errors?

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-5, associations

I am having trouble figuring out why rails is showing validation errors. The relevant details of my app are as follows:

1. Programs are offered in Sessions (many to many) (ProgramSession associates Program and Session)
2. Courses are offered by Instructors (many to many) (CourseInstructor associates Course and Instructors)
3. Exams are conducted and each Exam has many Papers.

I have generated all resources using scaffold.

**Problem:** when I try to create a [new paper](https://t4test.herokuapp.com/papers/new) Rails shows

> 2 errors prohibited this paper from being saved
>   - Program session must exist
>   - Course instructor must exist

Entire code is available on [github repo](https://github.com/beyond2013/ots), and has also been deployed on [heroku](https://t4test.herokuapp.com/)

I would really appreciate all the help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making following changes in `app/models/paper.rb` fixed the problem:

```
belongs_to :program_session, foreign_key: 'program_sessions_id'
belongs_to :course_instructor, foreign_key: 'course_instructors_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

check if the value and id of foreign-key is the same as it has set in DB.
and can you provide the controller and model to troubleshoot more

Comment: The entire code including model and controller is on github repo link i provide in the question